Identification of SOT-89 IC marked '8C924'
I have problem to identify a SOT-89 IC.
Anyone here who can help me with this?
My guess is a voltage regulator, but that's it.


Yes it is a L78L05ABUTR / L78L05ACUTR  5V voltage regulator from ST Microelectronics.

Picture from lcsc:


Thank you very much!

Just a note there are other regulators 8C9xx in the same package and xx is a lot number which could be "21"; but note the layout of the symbols are in two columns.
